# An error occurs if AdvanceTo() is used when PipeReader processes chunks

Tags: c#

I wrote a simple write/read example using `System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe`. Here is the complete code that can be run without error in a `.NET7.0` console program.

```cs
using System.Buffers;
using System.IO.Pipelines;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
  private static readonly int SizeOfChunk = 6;

  public static async Task Main(string[] args)
  {
    var pipe = new Pipe();
    await WriteSomeDataAsync(pipe.Writer);
    pipe.Writer.Complete();
    await ReadSomeDataAsync(pipe.Reader);
  }

  private static async ValueTask WriteSomeDataAsync(PipeWriter writer)
  {
    Memory<byte> memory = writer.GetMemory();
    var bytesWrite = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello stack overflow! My name is IsakGo.", memory.Span);
    writer.Advance(bytesWrite);
    await writer.FlushAsync();
  }

  private static async ValueTask ReadSomeDataAsync(PipeReader reader)
  {
    while (true)
    {
      ReadResult result = await reader.ReadAsync();
      ReadOnlySequence<byte> buffer = result.Buffer;

      if (buffer.IsEmpty && result.IsCompleted)
        break;

      while (buffer.Length >= SizeOfChunk)
      {
        ReadOnlySequence<byte> chunk = buffer.Slice(0, SizeOfChunk);

        foreach (ReadOnlyMemory<byte> segment in chunk)
        {
          var s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(segment.Span);
          Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

        buffer = buffer.Slice(SizeOfChunk);
        // reader.AdvanceTo(chunk.End);
      }

      reader.AdvanceTo(buffer.End);
    }
  }
}
```

My question has to do with the commented out `reader.AdvanceTo(chunk.End);` in the code above.

If I uncomment that part, I get an error.

```
Hello 
stack 
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: No reading operation to complete.
```

I used `reader.AdvanceTo(chunk.End)` to mark the data as used, but this code only works correctly without it.

Can you explain why I shouldn't use `reader.AdvanceTo(chunk.End)`?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27799) discussion - `ReadAsync` and `AdvanceTo` should be called in pairs (exactly). Your current code results in multiple `AdvanceTo` calls per read - hence the exception.